# Abstract come before title after `\maketitle`, how to correct

Tags: titles, abstract, front-matter

Why does come abstract before title in this example? And how to enforce the correct behaviour (title, authors, affiliations, abstract, such as in `elsarticle`?)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{authblk}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords:\ }} #1}
\begin{document}
\title{Absolute nothingness}
\author[1]{Someone}
\author[1]{Someone else}
\affil[1]{Some university}
\begin{abstract}
    We found absolutely nothing of interest. 
\end{abstract}
\keywords{no keywords, really}
\maketitle
big piece of nothing here
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The treatment of an abstract depends on how the particular document class was designed -- is it considered to be part of the "top matter".  For classes where the abstract is considered to be part of the top matter (apparently `elsarticle` and certainly `amsart`) it will be formatted and set by `\maketitle`.  Otherwise it will be processed as soon as it is encountered in the input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `article` class, `\author` and `\title` are commands that save their arguments and do not typeset anything, the typesetting is done by `\maketitle`, however `abstract` is a conventional typesetting environment, like `quote` or `center` that just typesets its content with a heading, so you need to place it after `\maketitle`.